# IBM server x 3850 (4X8core Xeon 7560), RedHat 5.6, free -mt on terminal shown only 32 GB?

Tags: redhat, ibm

I'm remotely SSH-ing an IBM server-x running RedHat 5.6. The server has 4 CPUs with 8 cores each, which is verified by cat /proc/cpuinfo

But free -mt show only the 32 G-RAM (which is correct for one CPU), not the expected 128 GB. Why is that? Is there some other way to check available memory ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the output of: `numactl --hardware`

Comment: I did, and found out a non-NUMA aware xen-kernel trolling my dom0. I would have checked your answer though if it wasn't a comment :-) Thanks!

Comment: Can you still post the output and fix for future generations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the output of `numactl --hardware`.

It may give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So with MikeyB's help, the problem was pinned down to a non NUMA aware kernel.

> > $> numactl --show
> >
> > No NUMA support available on this system.

Next step: consult kernel's docs and find out how to turn it NUMA aware (in xen, numa=on will do it), or init a kernel which is NUMA-aware by default S.A RHEL5.6. Both worked for me.